# println with anonymous function not printing expected value

Tags: scala

I wonder about Scala anonymous functions.

```
object hello { 
  def main(args: Array[String]) { 
    println ( ( (x:Int)=>return x+1)(1) ) 
  } 
}
```

I expected the result to be '2' but the output is blank. Was my assumption wrong?

Comment: `return` keyword in Scala doesn't do what you think it does. Never use it.

Comment: [It](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala#answer-2530007) will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of lambda is the result of the last statement in lambda body, so you could just add result value (in this case literal ()) as the last line.

return in lambda will return from the surrounding method rather than from the lambda itself using exception (NonLocalReturnControl).

In your case your return will return a Unit.

The valid code looks like:

`println ( ( (x:Int)=> x+1)(1) )`

Comment: my mistake is scala's annonymous function thought likes javascript's
ex (function(x){ return x+1 })(1)

Comment: *In your case your return will return a Unit.* what makes you think so?

Comment: From the error "warning: enclosing method main has result type Unit: return value discarded"

Answer (score 3):

I don't get a blank as you evoked result but the following compiler error:

```
scala> println ( ( (x:Int)=> return x+1)(1) )
<console>:8: error: return outside method definition
              println ( ( (x:Int)=> return x+1)(1) )
```

Remove the `return` keyword, often useless in Scala besides:

```
scala> println ( ( (x:Int)=>x+1)(1) )
2
```

Indeed, **`return` only ever returns from a method (defined with `def`).**
Your function literal call is not wrapped into a method body, that's why you have this error.

To illustrate, this code snippet would be valid:

```
scala> def wrappingMethod(): Int = {  //note this enclosing method
  ((x:Int)=> return x+1)(1)           // it's valid to call return here
}
     |      | wrappingMethod: ()Int

scala> wrappingMethod()
res3: Int = 2
```

Comment: I'm sorry My Run Envornment isn't REPL
I did on idea13 
object hello  {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println ( ( (x:Int)=>return x+1)(1) )

  }
}
thank you

Comment: @bistros This also returns a compiler error, using IDEA 13 too: `scala> object hello { def main(args: Array[String]) { println ( ( (x:Int)=>return x+1)(1) ) } }
<console>:7: warning: enclosing method main has result type Unit: return value discarded
       object hello { def main(args: Array[String]) { println ( ( (x:Int)=>return x+1)(1) ) } }`