# `return` in a scala function literal

Tags: function, scala, functional-programming, return, function-literal

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
var fun : (Int,Int) => Double = (a,b) =>
{
  // do something
  return 1.0
}
```

However, my IDE complaints with `Return statement outside method definition`. So how do I explicitly give a return statement in a function literal in scala?

Comment: I already answered a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24241486/985949

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Scala a `return` statement returns from the enclosing method body. If `return` appears inside of a function literal, it is implemented with exception throwing. `return` will throw an exception inside of the function which will then be caught be the enclosing method. Scala works this way in order to make the use of custom control constructs that take functions invisible, for example:

```
def geometricAverage(l: List[Double]): Double = {
  val product = l.foldLeft(1.0) { (z, x) =>
    if (x == 0) return 0 else z * x
  }
  Math.pow(product, 1.0 / l.length)
}
```

The `return` in this example returns from  the `geometricAverage` method, allowing it to complete instantly if a 0 is found. You don't need to know that `foldLeft` is a method that takes a function rather than a built-in construct to realize this.

The preference in Scala is to write functions in functional style, taking advantage of Scala's expression-oriented nature to make `return` unnecessary. For example:

```
val fun: (Int,Int) => Double = (a,b) => {
  if (a == b) {
    // side effect here, if desired
    0.0
  } else {
    // side effect here, if desired
    1.0
  }
}
```

If you really want to use `return` in the definition of the function, you can implement the appropriate function interface manually instead of using a function literal:

```
val fun = new Function2[Int, Int, Double] {
  def apply(x: Int, y: Int): Double = {
    if (x == y)
      return 0.0
    1.0
  }
}
```

But this is not idiomatic and strongly discouraged.

Comment: `return` can also be used to return from a named function.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use return, it makes Scala cry.

```
scala> var fun: (Int, Int) => Double = (a, b) => {
     | // do something
     | 1.0
     | }
fun: (Int, Int) => Double = <function2>

scala> fun(1, 2)
res4: Double = 1.0
```

Or better yet:

```
scala> def fun: (Int, Int) => Double = (a, b) => {
     | // do something
     | 1.0
     | }
fun: (Int, Int) => Double

scala> fun(1, 2)
res4: Double = 1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

> how do I explicitly give a return statement in a function literal in scala?

You can't. This is answered by [the language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) section 6.20, *Return Expressions*:

> A return expression `return e` must occur inside the body of some enclosing named
>   method or function.
>
> An `apply` method which is generated by the compiler as an expansion of an anonymous function does not count as a named function in the source program, and
>   therefore is never the target of a return expression.

Answer (score -9):

There is no `return` statement in Scala. In any function the last statement executed is the value returned. If this last statement doesn't comply with expected return type of the function, compiler will raise error.

Comment: This functional principle works across body of the function, according conditionals/loop; e.g. `if (cond) valReturnedIfCond else valReturnedElse`

Comment: There is indeed a return statement, and it can be used in imperative style code for early exits and the like.  It's frowned upon.

Comment: @DonRoby you're right, but imperative Scala is of no interest for me

Comment: Regardless of whether you're interested in it, "there is no `return` statement in Scala" simply isn't true.